# Can't seem to repeat reducebykey twice -- what is the new data structure?

Tags: scala, average

I am using the FCC data on census_block and broadband_provider_id. Here's the data https://transition.fcc.gov/form477/BroadbandData/Fixed/Dec19/Version%201/CA-Fixed-Dec2019.zip

I need to calculate the average number of providers per block for a state.

I keep on getting an error message! Help please!

```
//Define the package
package com.sundogsoftware.spark
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.log4j._


/** Compute the average number of providers by census block. */
object ProvidersByBlock {

  /** A function that splits a line of input into (block, providerid) tuples. */
  def parseLine(line: String): (Int, Int) = {
    // Split by commas
    val fields = line.split(",")
    // Extract the block and provider_ID fields, and convert to integers. Count col from 0
    val block = fields(9).toInt
    val providerid = fields(1).toInt
    // Create a tuple that is our result.
    (block, providerid)
  }

  /** Our main function where the action happens */
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // Set the log level to only print errors
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    // Create a SparkContext using every core of the local machine
    val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "ProvidersByBlock")

    // Load each line of the source data into an RDD
    val lines = sc.textFile("D:/NY-Fixed-Dec2019-v1.csv")

    // Use our parseLines function to convert to (block,provider_ID) tuples
    val rdd = lines.map(parseLine)


    //*** Count how many offers (NOT PROVIDERS) are per block
    // We are starting with an RDD of form (block, provider_ID) where block is the KEY and provider_ID is the VALUE
    // We will add 1 to each line so we can calculate the number of logs
    // We use mapValues to convert each provider_id  value to a tuple of (providerid, 1)
    // Then we use reduceByKey to sum up the total of 1s for total # of offers

    val totalsByblock = rdd.mapValues(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey((x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))

    // So now we have tuples of (blockid, a useless sum of provider id by block, n_offers)
    //We repeat the above to get # of blocks (could have passed it into the fn above too) to get averages
    val numofBlocks = totalsByblock.mapValues(x=>(x,1)).reduceByKey((x,y)=>(x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))
    val averagebyblock = numofBlocks.mapValues(x=> x._1 / x._2)

    // Collect the results from the RDD (This kicks off computing the DAG and actually executes the job)
    val results = averagebyblock.collect()

    // Sort and print the final results.
    results.sorted.foreach(println)


  }

}
```

Error message for this line:   val averagebyblock = numofBlocks.mapValues(x=> x._1 / x._2)
found   : (Int, Int)
required: String
val numofBlocks = totalsByblock.mapValues(x=>(x,1)).reduceByKey((x,y)=>(x._1+y._1, x._2 + y._2))

why does it require string in a division? and I tried with pos 2 and 3 (not sure where each calculation ends up honestly yet, was going to play with it) but I got the opposite error -- int required, found string. So I can't see to please that line :)

Thanks in advance! Super new! Be gentle!

Comment: I also don't think it's reading the data correctly: LogRecNo,Provider_Id,FRN,ProviderName,DBAName,HoldingCompanyName,HocoNum,HocoFinal,StateAbbr,BlockCode,TechCode,Consumer,MaxAdDown,MaxAdUp,Business
94391,53788,0003723822,"Level  3 Communications, LLC",CenturyLink,"CenturyLink, Inc.",130228,"CenturyLink, Inc.",NY,360010001001004,50,0,0,0,1
94392,53788,0003723822,"Level  3 Communications, LLC",CenturyLink,"CenturyLink, Inc.",130228,"CenturyLink, Inc.",NY,360010001001005,50,0,0,0,1

Comment: Error I get -- that's the wrong field  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "NY"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)

Answer (score 0):

Let's add some types:

```
val rdd: RDD[(Int, Int)] = lines.map(parseLine)
val totalsByblock: RDD[(Int, (Int, Int))] = 
  rdd                                                  // RDD[(Int, Int)]
    .mapValues(x => (x, 1))                            // RDD[(Int, (Int, Int))]
    .reduceByKey((x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)) // RDD[(Int, (Int, Int))]

val numofBlocks = 
  totalsByblock                                        // RDD[(Int, (Int, Int))]
    .mapValues(x=>(x,1))                               // RDD[(Int, ((Int, Int), Int))]
    .reduceByKey((x,y)=>(x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))    // RDD[(Int, ((Int, Int), Int))]

val averagebyblock = 
  numofBlocks.mapValues(x=> x._1 / x._2) // uhoh x is of type ((Int, Int), Int))
```

Note you probably simply want something like:

```
// Is that step even necessary?
// Can a provider be present multiple times for a given block?
val bpOccurrences: RDD[((Int, Int), Int)] = 
  rdd.map(bp => (bp, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

val bps: RDD[(Int, Int)] = 
  bpOccurrences.map { case ((b, _), occ) => ((b, occ), 1) }.reduceByKey(_ + _)

val (size, sum): (Int, Int) = 
  bps.aggregate((0, 0)) { case ((counter, acc), (_, p)) => (counter + 1, acc + p) }

val avg = (sum * 1D) / size
```

Comment: Yes a provider can appear twice (rare, you are correct, I think about 90%) -- if a provider is both suppliying DSL and fiber for instance, they will file 2 reports for a block with 2 different maxspeeds.

Comment: Thank you, let me try this. Very readable code, thank you!

Comment: Thank you, that helped! Would spark/scala have an issue reading this? Why is my error pulling from field 8 rather than 9?  Could the text fields be causing some issues and I need to define better how to read it in? TIA LogRecNo,Provider_Id,FRN,ProviderName,DBAName,HoldingCompanyName,HocoNum,HocoFinal,StateAbbr,BlockCode,TechCode,Consumer,MaxAdDown,MaxAdUp,Business 94391,53788,0003723822,"Level 3 Communications, LLC",CenturyLink,"CenturyLink, Inc.",130228,"CenturyLink, Inc.",NY,360010001001004,50,0,0,0,1